# Trying to print a part of each line in sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to use sed to print just the last part of the url from a list of data. I want it to be using sed not awk.

Input data is like this:

```
Place,AF,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benin
Place Mat,NA,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Barthelemy
Orion,NA,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bermuda
```

I want to just print the last part of the URL like this (WANT THIS):

```
Benin
Saint Barthelemy
Bermuda
```

I'm having so much trouble with the / and \ because they exist in the url!!!

My attempt so far (tryng to replace stuff I don't want with nothing)

```
sed -r s/$.+wikipedia\.org\/// in.txt
```

Also I need to replace spaces with _ but I can use the y command y/_/ / I think?

Comment: I think you have used $ instead of ^. ^ means the beginning and $ means the end. You can replace the `/` with any other character, like Cyrus showed. And you quote the sed commands to avoid problems with spaces for instance.

Comment: For those who are interested in awk: use `/` as separator, replace with a regex in last column (`$NF`) all `_` by blanks and then print last column (`$NF`): `awk -F / '{gsub(/_/, " ", $NF); print $NF}' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/.*\///;s/_/ /g' file
```

or replace first `s///` by `s||||` to avoid escaping:

```
sed 's|.*/||;s/_/ /g' file
```

Output:

```
Benin
Saint Barthelemy
Bermuda
```

Comment: So that's how you did it, It kept givein me trouble since sed uses the slash